# Block direct access to php files (only rewrited) using nginx

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I have files like Ucp.php Somesite.php and i want to create a rewrite rules for nginx. This is not problematic.

But i also want to block direct access to those php files, so that enetring http://mysite.com/Ucp.php will return 404 Not Found.

There is a solution for apache (using THE_REQUEST), but how can I do this on nginx?

```
server
{
        listen 80;
        server_name site.com;
        root /home/site/public_html;

        index Main.php;
        rewrite ^/SomeAddr/$ /SomeAddr.php last;
        rewrite ^/SomeOtherAddr/$ /SomeOtherAddr.php last;


        location ~ \.php$
        {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/site_com.sock;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }
        include security.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`internal` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) for this purpose.

```
location ~ \.php$
{
        internal;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/site_com.sock;
        include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Shows 404, can we change 404 to something else?

Answer (score -2):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  return 404;
}
```

Comment: Nope? It blocks every php file even if its rewrited. Haven't you read my post?

Comment: You say nothing about your config... Did you use fastcgi_pass?

Comment: Yes, of course I do. The only thing I want to change is to block urls containng .php

Comment: config is now in the first post